# Stop NSStream runloop in same NSThread

Tags: multithreading, nsthread, nsstream, nsrunloop

I'm trying to run `NSStreams` in a thread in my project. I created a thread below:

```
self.thread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(createStreams:) object:handler];
[self.thread start];
```

And the thread selector implementation is blow:

```
- (void)createStreams:(OpenStreamHandler)handler {

assert(![[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread]); // make sure this thread is not a main thread

// open input
[self.inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[self.inputStream open];

// open output
[self.outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[self.outputStream open];

[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run]; // start a run loop, look at the next point }
```

Right now I want to remove that stream `runloop` running in that thread using something like:

```
// Shut down input
[self.inputStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[self.inputStream close];
self.inputStream = nil;

// Shut down output
[self.outputStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[self.outputStream close];
self.outputStream = nil;
```

How could I run above code in the correct thread (get right `currentRunLoop`) without using method swizzling?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1414476-performselector).

```
  - (void)closeStreams {
    // Shut down input
    [self.inputStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [self.inputStream close];
    self.inputStream = nil;

    // Shut down output
    [self.outputStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [self.outputStream close];
    self.outputStream = nil;
}

- (void)closeStreamsOnTread:(NSThread *)aThread {
    SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"closeStreams");
    [self performSelector:selector onThread:aThread withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```